# Trying to insert into websql table from Json, using each()

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, web-sql, each

I'm currently working on a phonegap app, wich must sync with a distant mysql server.

I load a json file using getJson() and insert the rows into a websql database. My problems is that only the first row is inserted in the websql DB. I actally got two rows in the Json file.

Here is my function:

```
function loadJson(){


$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8888/results.json", function( data ) { 

    $.each(data, function(i, item) { 

        var title=data[i].title;           
        var content=data[i].content;            
        var imgurl=data[i].imgurl;
        imgName = imgurl.substring(imgurl.lastIndexOf('/'))
        db.transaction(function (transaction) {
            console.log('we insert' + title); // It works, display me the two different title
            transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO projets (title, content, imgurl) VALUES ("' + title + '","' + content + '", "' + imgurl + '" );'); //Only the first row is inserted
        });

    });
});
```

My code may be horrible, i'm still a "newbie". Anyway, thank you in advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions are meant to process many requests to the DB at a time. Instead of starting multiple transactions, try using one transaction for all SQL statements.

Example (may need some improvements):

```
function loadJson(){
    $.getJSON( "http://localhost:8888/results.json", function( data ) { 
        db.transaction(function (transaction) {
            var len = data.length;
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var title=data[i].title;           
                var content=data[i].content;            
                var imgurl=data[i].imgurl;
                imgName = imgurl.substring(imgurl.lastIndexOf('/'));
                console.log('we insert' + title); // It works, display me the two different title
                transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO projets (title, content, imgurl) VALUES (?,?,?)',[title, content, imgurl]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When starting a transaction the database/table get locked for that instance. If you call multiple transactions the first locks-up everything and the rest cannot complete.

Additionally I have replaced the `.each` with a `for` as there is great performance gain in using `for` over `.each`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code, but it does'nt insert anything in my websql db anymore. I have know idea why. I also replaced ".lenght()" by ".lenght" since it was displaying me an error (number is not a function).  I didnt know for the .each and for thanks.

Comment: I have updated the example, again it is an example you may not be able to copy paste it. I noticed the table name was `projets` that may be a typo. I also fixed the `length` issue and update the `executeSql` to escape the input values. These updates may work for you now.

Comment: Thanks after some correction it worked ! There was no typo error on `projets`, its my table name actually (its the french for projects). Also on the `imgName` declaration, i had some problem with the `imgurl.lastIndexOf(‘/‘))` i replaced it by `imgurl.lastIndexOf('/'))` and it worked well. Thank you again !

Comment: Sorry for the `‘/‘` issue, I was using textEdit on a Mac and it replaced the correct ones. And thank you for explaining the table name. glad it worked :)